# Custom Logging Module for IIS

Tags: c++, iis, logging, module

I have an application which exposes its COM method as

```
Sub InsertLog(ByVal time As Date, ByVal siteName As String, ByVal requestPath As String, ByVal remoteHost As String, ByVal referrer As String, ByVal outBytes As Long Long, ByVal inBytes As Long Long)
```

I tried the using the  [ILogPlugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524607%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to make a custom logging module which will transfer data to this method. However I was not able to recieve any event on my IIS 7.5.

I have to implement this module for IIS 6 and later, and this has to support logging for FTP and HTTP(S). I know about Global-Level HTTP Module but I really doubt its working on IIS6 and for FTP. Also I dont know how to retrieve the logging informations from these HTTP modules.

Request you to please provide any link or even a smaller guidance to achieve the objective.
I have to program it in C++.

Thanks for your support....

Answer (score 5):

Iis 7.5 must be configured with the custom logging module or your com object that implements ilogplugin will not be called

See the following for more info

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview

And

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259552

The recommended method for iis 7.5 is described  here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689225(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Mike hit the nail on the head. There is a quote in his first link that states - "We do not not recommend extending IIS using this interface. Instead, customers should write a module and subscribe to the RQ_LOG_REQUEST notification". Further things to note are that if the site is using integrated mode, then the module registration in web.config differs from IIS6 to IIS7+. Look at something like [this](http://marshallzhao.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/register-httpmodule-in-iis6-and-iis7.html) to get an idea of the changes.